# Concatenate string from one column based on id from another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I've got two DataFrame that looks like this

```
    A   B
    1   a1
    2   b2
    1   a3
    2   b4
```

And I want to concat with space strings from B column based on value in A. 
So final version should look like:

```
    A   B
    1   a1 a3
    2   b2 b4
```

Could someone give me any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby`

```
df.groupby('A').B.apply(' '.join)
```

Reset the index if you want

```
df.groupby('A').B.apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: Okay but now I've got "expected str instance, float found" error